# jqueryUI dialog - закрыть окно

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Доброго дня! 
Не могу понять в чем проблема. Данный код вызывает диалоговое окно, в котором через айфрейм грузится страница с формой. После нажатия на кнопку "сохранить", в диалоговом окне, наше окно должно закрываться, а данные на странице обновиться через аякс.(т.е. то что введено во всплывашке переноситься потом в формы на самой странице.)

Проблема моя в том, что при нажатии на "сохранить", данные обновляются, но всплываха диалоговая не закрывается. Получается, что пользователю приходится руками жмакать по крестику. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

P.S. Работаю с хромом и IE.

Код:

```
var $dialog = null;

$(function(){
showModalDialog = function(url,dialogArguments,width,height,scrollable,id_link_refresh,direction_refresh, self) {
    console.log("url", url);

    var defaultOptns = {
        url: url,
        dialogArguments: dialogArguments,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        position: 'center',
        resizable: true,
        scrollable: scrollable,
        onClose: function() {

            refresh_links(id_link_refresh, direction_refresh); },
            returnValue: null,
            doPostBackAfterCloseCallback: false,
            postBackElementId: null
        };
        options=defaultOptns;

        var fns = {
            close: function() {
                opts.returnValue = $dialog.returnValue;
                $dialog = null;
                opts.onClose(function(){refresh_links(id_link_refresh, direction_refresh);});
                if (opts.doPostBackAfterCloseCallback) {
                    postBackForm(opts.postBackElementId);
                }
            },
            adjustWidth: function() { $frame.css("width", "100%"); }
        };



var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptns, options);

var $frame = $('<iframe id="iframeDialog" />');

if (opts.scrollable)
    $frame.css('overflow', 'auto');

$frame.css({
    'padding': 0,
    'margin': 0,
    'padding-bottom': 10
});

console.log();

var $dialogWindow = $frame.dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 width: opts.width,
 height: opts.height,
 resizable: opts.resizable,
 id:'modalDialog',
 position: opts.position,

 overlay: {
    opacity: 0.5,
    background: "black"
},
close: fns.close,
resizeStop: fns.adjustWidth
});

$dialogWindow.dialog('open');
$frame.attr('src', opts.url);
console.log(opts);
fns.adjustWidth();

$frame.load(function() {
    if ($dialogWindow) {

        var maxTitleLength = 50;
        var title = $(this).contents().find("title").html();
        if (title.length > maxTitleLength) {
            title = title.substring(0, maxTitleLength) + '...';
        }
        $dialogWindow.dialog('option', 'title', title);
    }
});

$dialog = new Object();
$dialog.dialogArguments = opts.dialogArguments;
$dialog.dialogWindow = $dialogWindow;
$dialog.returnValue = null;
dialogRules={
    cancel: function (){
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
}
var self=this;

$('#btn_close').bind("click", function(){   
  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
  });

}
});
function postBackForm(targetElementId) {
var theform;
theform = document.forms[0];
theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = targetElementId;
theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = "";
theform.submit();
location.reload();

}
```

Comment: предполагаю, что при нажатии на кнопку, он закрывает айфрейм, а окно по этому остается и просто заново подгружает мой айфрейм. Но я тогда не понимаю, как подняться на "уровень выше" и закрыть все окно...

Comment: Добавьте свой код в http://jsfiddle.net/ и прикрепите ссылку к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию JQuery не видит DOM в iframe, где, вероятно, находится ваша кнопка, для этого необходимо использовать [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: во - спасибо, я догадывался о чем-то подобном, но что именно искать не знал. Сейчас буду смотреть. Позже отпишусь о результате. Спасибо!